# How can I copy data from dataframe 'A' to dataframe 'B'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `dataframes` with equal number of `rows` and `columns`.

I want to copy the values from Dataframe A:

```
   0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |...|300|
0| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |     "
1| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |     "
2| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |     "
...|                   "
98|                    "
```

into Dataframe B while retaining Dataframe B's indices:

```
   a | b | c | d |...|300|
a| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |     "
b| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |     "
c| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |     "
...|                   "
98|                    "
```

I have tried reindexing dataframe A to match Dataframe B but the values in every row/column get lost as seen above.

Comment: `dfb=dfa.copy()`?

Comment: `dfa.index = dfb.index`